# Magento2: Errors from console static/_cache/merged

Tags: error, design, console

[image]

I have a lot of error on my production mode. Console has two errors that related with **`static/_cache/merged`** folder.This error appears only on my main store, other store views show the right design, but the main store broke design for homepage and catalog. Any ideas that commands can solve this problem? In my staging there are no errors or problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved. In Admin panel -> System -> Cache Management -> Flush Cache Storage [image]